# why here not creating table?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table login
(
    meter_no number(30,5), 
    username varchar2(20), 
    name varchar2(20), 
    password varchar2(20), 
    user varchar2(20)
);

create table login
(
    meter_no number(30,5), 
    username varchar2(20), 
    name varchar2(20), 
    password varchar2(20), 
    user varchar2(20)
)
```

> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: Probably one of your column names is an Oracle key word, like `PASSWORD`

Comment: but user column have some problem

Comment: when i change user column so it is creating.

Comment: As @TangentiallyPerpendicular stated, one of your columns is a reserved word in Oracle. If you look at the list of reserved words it should be obvious which one is causing the issue

Comment: ok thanku..i will check reserve word

Comment: You could also see what Oracle23c has to say about this: [ORA-03050: invalid identifier: "USER" is a reserved word](https://dbfiddle.uk/HYN9p31C)   (Because 18c says: [ORA-00904: : invalid identifier](https://dbfiddle.uk/9q4W4EVZ))  Newer versions seem to show more info.